# AppSettings string new lines not recognised after numbers

Tags: c#

I have the following email signature stored in appsettings:

```
<add key="EmailSignature"
           value="&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;Smokey Bear&#13;&#10;Forest Manager&#13;&#10;Level 7 Tree House&#13;&#10;JellyStone Park&#13;&#10;DDI 04 548 6457 • M 021 456 7854 • F 04 548 456" />
```

The problem is it comes out in the email looking like:

Smokey Bear
Forest Manager
Level 7 Tree HouseJellyStone ParkDDI 04 548 6457 • M 021 456 7854 • F 04 548 456

After some experimentation I've found it's caused by the numbers. So the 7 in "Level 7" is causing the JellyStone Park to be on the same line. Likewise the other numbers would cause further problem if there were further lines.

Anyone know how to fix this? Do I need to escape a character?

**EDIT:**

So I've found if I use `&#55;` in place of the 7 it fixes the problem caused by the 7. However this isn't very desirable because it makes the data hard to read and edit.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to have some sort of identifying Key in AppSettings, and then having a static string in your code itself that you can use to set the email Signature.

I imagine if you want to set an email signature in AppSettings you might want to change it based on the level?